# Unable to start service with intent. Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android

I can't believe why this code not working. I tried several times but to no avail, how can I solve this problem, how are you doing it?

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/StartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/StopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> java (CameraRecorder Class)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CameraRecorder extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = CameraRecorder.class.getSimpleName();

    public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    public static Camera mCamera;
    public static boolean mPreviewRunning;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartService);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraRecorder.this, RecorderService.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startService(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopService);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                stopService(new Intent(CameraRecorder.this, RecorderService.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }
}
```

> java (RecorderService Class)

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class RecorderService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static Camera mServiceCamera;
    private boolean mRecordingStatus;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mRecordingStatus = false;
        mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
        mSurfaceView = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceView;
        mSurfaceHolder = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceHolder;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (mRecordingStatus == false)
            startRecording();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopRecording();
        mRecordingStatus = false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean startRecording(){

        try {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
            Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

            final List<Size> listPreviewSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            for (Size size : listPreviewSize) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Supported Preview Size (%d, %d)", size.width, size.height));
            }

            Size previewSize = listPreviewSize.get(0);
            p.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mServiceCamera.unlock();

            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4");
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();

            mRecordingStatus = true;

            return true;

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mServiceCamera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
        mMediaRecorder.release();

        mServiceCamera.release();
        mServiceCamera = null;
    }
}
```

> Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.camerarecorder">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.example.camerarecorder.CameraRecorder"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.camerarecorder.RecorderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you asked for Runtime permission ? for camera and Audio ?

Comment: @ADM no , how can i doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you haven't ask for the runtime permission

```
private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};

 if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
    startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
}
```

Calling Permssion Context

```
 private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

    for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

if Permission not granted

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much my friend , you was large part in solution

Comment: if my question really helped you please click the tick button.... let the people know it solved thank u...

Comment: im new on this site , so i didn't know where the tick button , where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the camera dependency in gradle file.